# Nodejs: how override log file when reach file size limit without createSymlink enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I have a NodeJS service running inside docker and mounting the log file to other service (docker) that load the file and export it to ES (I will name it the exporter).
for some reason the exporter can not load symlink file, and it can not load a "regex" file names. which mean rotating and changing the file name each time.

then, I need log file with permanent name and once file size reached then override it.

today by using Winston File transporter once the max size reached it just stop logging, unless the service restart.
here is my transporter configuration:

```
const dailyTransport = new winston.transports.File({
        level: 'debug',
        dirname: 'logs',
        filename: service_name.log,
        datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
        handleExceptions: true,
        zippedArchive: false,
        json: false,
        maxsize: 1000000, // 1mb
        maxFiles: 1
    });
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

I need log file with permanent name (not to be rotate) and once file size reached then override it without the need to restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the answer, I had to add `rotationFormat: () => ''`
so the rotation format name will not change the filename, then it will override it.

so it will look like:

```
const dailyTransport = new winston.transports.File({
    level: 'debug',
    dirname: 'logs',
    rotationFormat: () => ''
    filename: service_name.log,
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
    handleExceptions: true,
    zippedArchive: false,
    json: false,
    maxsize: 1000000, // 1mb
    maxFiles: 1
});
```